# java for loop issue, int i returning zero but loop running fine

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop, jtable

I have a JTable that uses a DefaultTableModel, I got the result in the array but after the execution of the for loop, `int i` will always print zero value. The loop is working fine.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49OWI.png)

```
Ramalan forecast = model.ramalan(12);
DefaultTableModel tb = new DefaultTableModel();
String header[] = new String[] { "No", "tgl", "harga", "Batas Atas", "Batas Bawah" };
tb.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
Vector<Object> rml = new Vector<>();
for(int i=0; i<forecast.estimasiPoin().ukuran(); i++){
    rml.add(i);
    rml.add("");
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.estimasiPoin().pada(i)));
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.intervalPrediksiAtas().pada(i)));
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.intervalPrediksiAtas().pada(i)));
     tb.addRow(rml);
}
tableRamal.setModel(tb);
```

Here's how it's supposed to print the values:

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
    rml.add(i);
    rml.add("");
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.estimasiPoin().pada(i)));
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.intervalPrediksiAtas().pada(i)));
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.intervalPrediksiAtas().pada(i)));
     tb.addRow(rml);
}
tableRamal.setModel(tb);
```

but it is still returning zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-using the same vector and just adding more elements on to the end.

Change your code to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<forecast.estimasiPoin().ukuran(); i++){
    Vector<Object> rml = new Vector<>();
    rml.add(i);
    rml.add("");
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.estimasiPoin().pada(i)));
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.intervalPrediksiAtas().pada(i)));
    rml.add(aturDesim.format(forecast.intervalPrediksiAtas().pada(i)));
    tb.addRow(rml);
}
```